# Local mail delivery affected by method of root login

Tags: root, mail-command

I just sent a local mail using the following syntax:

```
echo "Testing" | mail -s "This is just a test" root@localhost
```

Then I log into root using:

```
sudo -i
```

And check my mail. The message is there.
If I repeat the mail command and log into root using:

```
su root
```

The mail is not in my mailbox. In both cases I am logging into the root account, so what is happening here? It's a fairly new, basic installation of CentOS 7.

I even checked again by logging in using su and when it wasn't there I logged out and back in using sudo -i and sure enough, the mail was there.

Comment: What happens with `su - root`?  (Note the `-` argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this behavior is the `MAIL` environment variable. When you switch to root with

```
sudo -i
```

you simulate an intial login (`-i`) and the `MAIL` environment variable is set to `/var/spool/mail/root`. When you switch to root with

```
su root
```

The `MAIL`environment variable stay to its old value i.e. `/var/spool/mail/jo` and the command `mail` check the mailbox of the user and not the mailbox of root. This why you see it empty.

Comment: Brilliant answer. You got it spot on. I tried logging into root with sudo -i, then echo $MAIL gives /var/spool/mail/root. Then I try the other way with su root and I get /var/spool/mail/user.       Perfect answer. Thanks.